# SwaggerUI shows messages like "Could not resolve reference: Not Found"

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

currently I'm developing a .Net Core 3.1 Service with SwaggerUI. Actually I'm getting Errors in the Swagger UI:
[image: Swagger UI Errors]

When I look into the DevTools of my Browser I see that the SwaggerUI makes the following wrong call:

[image: Swagger Address]

Background is: My Service is hosted as a Subpage on an IIS. Therefore I configured Swagger as following (Startup.cs):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection()
        .UseRouting()
        .UseAuthentication()
        .UseAuthorization()
        .UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers())
        .UseSwagger()
        .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                        {
                            c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", ServiceConstants.ServiceDisplayName);
                            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
                        });
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
                                    {
                                        options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
                                        options.ForwardClientCertificate = true;
                                    });
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = ServiceConstants.ServiceDisplayName, Description = ServiceConstants.ServiceDescription, Version = "v1" }));
}
```

I already tried without the relative Path `./swagger/v1/swagger.json` but this only works locally. I .NetCore 2.1 I never had such an issue.

an Example of my Controller is this:

```
[Authorize, Route(nameof(AdminController))]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost, Route(nameof(ClearAllCaches))]
    public void ClearAllCaches()
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

I already read a lot of possible solutions but they all won't work with .NetCore 3.1. I'm using the following NugetPackages for Swagger:

[image: Nuget Packages]

Swagger itself works fine, but the errors are a bit anoying. Does somebody has a clue?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The url being requested seems to duplicate `/swagger/v1` e.g `https://yoururl/swagger/v1/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

I would have a look at the swashbuckle setup. Try:

- remove the `.` from `SwaggerEndpoint`
- delete the `c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;`

Comment: That's what I've already tried. But then Swagger won't load anymore on the Server, because the Website is in a Subpage like this: https://myserver/MySubPage/. Without the dot it will locate the swagger json at https://myserver/swagger/v1/swagger.json instead of https://myserver/MySubPage/swagger/v1/swagger.json